# Page session in php, I want to store the time spent by the user on a particular page...?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can any one help in storing the time spent by user on a particular page...
This is what I did...
It seams to work but i don't know my my php page is unable to get the data and store in database...
individually while I am calling StoreTime.php?time=23 it is getting the time value and storing the data...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Page time
    </title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var time=1;

    function timeHere() 
    {
        time = time + 1;
        finalTime = time / 10;
        document.title = finalTime;
    }

    function sayTime() 
    {
        finalTime = time / 10;
        showTime(finalTime);
        alert("U are in this page for " +finalTime+" Sec");
    }


    function showTime(finalTime)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","StoreTime.php?time=" +finalTime,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function sendTimeSpent(finalTime)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/Test/Timer/StoreTime.php?time="+finalTime,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
</script>   
<body onload='window.setInterval("timeHere()", 100)' onunload="sayTime()">
    Close the page to see the time spent on this page...
    <div id='myDiv'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. BTW, it can be done by combining JS and PHP. And also provide in some details about your question

Comment: Are you looking for a server-side-only solution or server+client solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- Paste this code into an external JavaScript file named: timePage.js  -->

/* This script and many more are available free online at
The JavaScript Source :: http://javascript.internet.com
Created by: Cody Shaffer :: http://codytheking313.byethost11.com */

var time=1;

function timeHere() {
  time = time + 1;
  finalTime = time / 10;
/* Remove the "//" below to display in the title bar
  the amount of time the visitor has been on the site.
  Be aware though, that it does tend to be a bit distracting. */
// document.title = finalTime+" seconds you been here for!";
}

function sayTime() {
  finalTime = time / 10;
  alert("Thank you for coming to my site! \n You have been here " + finalTime + " seconds!");
}



<!-- Paste this code into the HEAD section of your HTML document.
     You may need to change the path of the file.  -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="timePage.js"></script>



<!-- Paste this code into the BODY tag -->

<body onload='window.setInterval("timeHere()", 100)' onunload="sayTime()">
```

Here is some code on [this](http://javascript.internet.com/time-date/time-spent-on-page.html) site. Now as you can use this script to calculate the time spent, on the other side of the coin, you can use AJAX to continuosly send the time duration to a php file the server for futher workout with the data.

Comment: `individually while I am calling StoreTime.php?time=23 it is getting the time value and storing the data...` what do mean to say by this?

Comment: @codign-Freak: I have send get data like this...
http://localhost/Test/StoreTime.php?time=23
this working, means getting the time and storing it into the database...

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET","/Test/Timer/StoreTime.php?time="+finalTime,true);` check this line

Comment: in the above comment you mentioned a different path, and you are making a ajax request to some other path