# Call a php function when a page unload

Tags: javascript, php

I develop a elearning courses for student using php. When a student leave from the course page how much time he spent should be recorded.

No i use javascript window.onuload and window.onbeforeload to call php function to track time using ajax. But it is not work properly.

It is possible to call a php function from server side when a page unload?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be much better off sending a heartbeat signal to the PHP page on some interval when the user is on the site, say every 30 seconds. Then, total the time spent based on all the heartbeats received.

Send them with ajax, and total them in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

No. Once the server sends the page to the browser it has no control or insight as to what happens on the page. Using JavaScript as you described above is the only way to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Most sites store the time of page load as a session or similar then when the page is refreshed or another page is loaded, the time spent on the page is calculated and stored separately.

Example:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['lasttime'])){
        $_SESSION['totaltime'] += time() - $_SESSION['lasttime']; //Add seconds onto total time
    }
    $_SESSION['lasttime'] = time();
    //...
?>
```

if you mean to detect when they leave the site completely then it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is for. It keeps track of visitors to your website and reports statistics to you like such as length of visit. They even [offer an API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) to help you get this information.

if you want don't get anysolution plz refer the below links

1)  **[How do I know how long a user or a single IP address spent on a page of my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462866/how-do-i-know-how-long-a-user-or-a-single-ip-address-spent-on-a-page-of-my-site)**
2) **[Page session in php, I want to store the time spent by the user on a particular page…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235390/page-session-in-php-i-want-to-store-the-time-spent-by-the-user-on-a-particular)**
3) **[time user spent on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421637/time-user-spent-on-the-page)**
4) **[time spent by user on a web page until he submits the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194066/time-spent-by-user-on-a-web-page-until-he-submits-the-form)**

i hope this link and answer is useful for you.. :-)